# Site to talk with people from German speaking areas

Tags: speaking

Is there a good site to talk with people from German speaking areas to improve my German ?

Comment: please be more specific about "talk". "talk" as in "speech" or "talk" as in "communicate"? Why not come to [chat]?

Comment: Yes, I mean on chatting or any other kind of correspondence. Thanks

Comment: There are a number of tandem websites; google?

Comment: Sicher nicht unser Chat - da redet man nur Englisch! :) (Just kidding). Aber er könnte zu schwach besucht sein.

Comment: If you want written communication, just become a member of any German forum on any topic you are interested in. Use Google and "forum GermanWordForYourInterest" (without quotation marks) to find relevant forums, e.g. https://www.google.de/#q=forum+flugzeuge

Comment: It is hard. Germany has 30% immigrants... this explains everything. I love them, I understand them, but I am very far from their circles. Good luck! It will be MUCH harder as you think.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean talking when you say chatting then you could search for an open german [teamspeak](http://teamspeak.de) server or try to find [german skype contacts](http://www.lingq.com) or [another tandem partner](http://www.skb.tu-berlin.de/contao/index.php/en/tandem.html).

When you are a gamer you could try to install your games in german and use the ingame voice chat when playing with german people.
Another possibility would be speech recognition. When you own a Xbox One, try to control it with german speech commands.

If you only want to chat with words, you could search for open german [irc channels](http://www.mirc.com/), german forums or any other german chat.

Answer (score 0):

Try [knuddels.de](http://www.knuddels.de/), it requires email registration but it's a very popular German website for chatting.

Comment: When I was young, that was a kiddies' chat. Has it changed?

Comment: It is very popular for kids but there are also many adults to chat with.

It not only very popular but actually the biggest (in terms of active users - over 1.000.000) German website for chatting.

Comment: Aaand what kind of language will he encounter there?

Comment: Lllanguage of everyday life.

Comment: I didn't even know that the site is still online!

Comment: Yes it is @PattaFeuFeu

Answer (score 0):

If you like to improve your German, you should consider to watch the German news on ARD and ZDF.

The speakers are special trained to speak loud and clear with very good German.

There might be an IP restriction, but if you find a German proxy server, you can find a lot of German stuff in the [ZDF-Mediathek](http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek#/hauptnavigation/nachrichten).

If you whant to speak with Germans, I believe the best way is to get in touch via social media. You can use Knuddels.de or Jappy.de which are very popular teenage-dating-sites. The problem is that the spoken and written German you can learn there is very bad.

I would recommend you to use Facebook, think of your hobby and interest, translate them into German and serch for them. Find German groups whitch you can join. Speak with the people there, and invite them to chat with you. I believe, Facebook has a built-in voicechat function.